# Value of 'cost per Unit' in the Extracted report from admanager API different than that in the GAM UPI. Why and how is the conversion done?

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

Suppose if the value of Line item (Cost per Unit) is $45.45 in the report that we get from Google Ad Manager 360 UI , the same report when extracted through a java application using ad manager API gives value '45454000' . Why is this conversion done ? is it specific to any API version? I'm using v202111 in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Google Ads and Ads Manager (not sure about Campaign Manager and DV360) internally use "micros"—i.e. a millionth of the base unit of a given currency—for monetary values.

Presumably this is being done so they can use integers and don't have to deal with fixed-point math. You'll just have to divide all the values reported by the API by 1'000'000.